# How do I create a (custom) alignment guide in Pixelmator

Tags: alignment, pixelmator, guides

How do I add a custom/fixed alignment guide in Pixelmator? I know it's possible because I done it before and I'm working with a file that already has three, but I need to add one more. How is that done?

Answer (score 1):

Found it: http://help.pixelmator.com/mac/3.2/#430

This is the procedure:

1. Select View > Show Rulers.
2. Do one of the following:

   - Click and drag any of the horizontal or vertical ruler bars and drop the guideline anywhere onto your image.
   - Double-click the horizontal or vertical ruler bars and choose New guide from the shortcut menu in order to open a Place a Guide sheet. Select a horizontal or vertical orientation and enter a position at which the guide should be placed. Click OK after you are done.
   - Hold down the Option key as you drag away from the vertical ruler in order to create a horizontal guide and vice versa.

Tip: Hold down the Shift key as you drag a guide to make it snap to the ruler ticks.

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge the PXM Version 3.3.2 Limestone (50417) cannot create custom guides, but only regular straight ones.

My way to use any object as a guide is a relatively new feature "Lock layer" - I create thin lines/objects and lock them, thus they are used as a guides:

---

The horizontal line is a regular guide of pxm, the diagonal - straight lines locked and used as custom guides.

[image]